# How can I prevent scrolling outside to the hidden navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

[image: where user is able to scroll to]

I've made a navbar which shows up from the right of the screen when the user clicks on the hamburger menu. When I've tested the page I am able to scroll to the hidden navigation bar, whats a way to prevent this ? overflow?

```
nav {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
min-height: 2vh;
font-family: var(--ff-primary);
background-color: var(--clr-accent);}

.nav-links{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
width: 30%;
z-index: 9999; 
}

.nav-links li{
list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
color: var(--clr-dark);
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
}

    .logo{
    color: var(--clr-dark);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.burger div{
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--clr-dark);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 55%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){

   .nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 5vh;
    background-color: var(--clr-accent);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;

   }

   .nav-links a{

   }
   .nav-links li{
       opacity: 1;
   }
   .burger{
       display: block;

   }
}
.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);

}
```

this is my css code for the navbar, it is a hamburger on mobile and on regular screen size its just a navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is "hidden" unsuccessfully by positioning it 0px from the right:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
   .nav-links{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Try using negatives for your positioning, it positions elements outside of the view which prevents the ability to scroll them into view:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
   .nav-links{
      position: absolute;
      right: -100%;
  }
}
```